# Call a single function in one script in R from another script

Tags: r

I want to call a specific function that I built in a script in R into another script. I don't want to use the source function since it will evaluate the script where the function to be call is stored. Do you know any option to perform this job?

Comment: Build a package ...

Comment: I usually save all the auxiliar functions into a script and then use `source` function. You probably do not want to use it because you have examples, . . . I recomend you to create a scritp where only the functions are defined.

Comment: The source command accepts a connection, so you could plausibly open the script file, send only the lines related to your function to a new connection, and source that - but this is madness, just move or copy your function to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29132294/5224236), The below checks where in your source file you define functions, and evaluates these lines only.

```
cmds <- parse("fakeload.R")
assign.funs <- sapply(cmds, function(x) {
   if(x[[1]]=="<-") {
       if(x[[3]][[1]]=="function") {
           return(TRUE)
       }
   }
   return(FALSE)
})
eval(cmds[assign.funs])
```

However, this is not the right way to do this in R. Write a script with only functions that you can reuse as many times as you want in other scripts using `source`, without the need of defining more logic (functions to call functions).

When you'll want to load the same function into another script for example, you'll have to copy/paste this code again. If many scripts use the same function, modifying this "function-loading" logic will cause you some headaches.

fair warning ;)